# How to put string for attribute to function

Tags: python, function, attributes, ccxt

I need help with function attribute in Python.
I have the data which look like this: `exch1 = data['Info']['Exchange1']` and this equals for example `poloniex`.
I need to get `exch1_object` which must look like this `ccxt.poloniex()`, But when I try to do it I get the error:

```
AttributeError: module 'ccxt' has no attribute 'str'
```

```
import ccxt
exch1 = data['Info']['Exchange1']
exch2 = data['Info']['Exchange2']
exch1_object = exch1.lower()
exch1_object = ccxt.str(exch1_object)()
```

Comment: `ccxt.str` evidently doesn't exist. What is it supposed to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to use [`getattr()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr):

```
# 'exch1_object' should be a string
func = getattr(ccxt, exch1_object)
exch1_object = func()
```

This will get the function from the module `ccxt` that has the name that is currently inside the variable `exch1_object` (which should be a string).

This can also be shortened to this:

```
exch1_object = getattr(ccxt, exch1_object)()
```

you will have to decide which is clearer and more readable for your case.

---

So, for example, these lines:

```
exch1_object = 'poloniex'
exch1_object = getattr(ccxt, exch1_object)()
```

will yield the same results as:

```
exch1_object = ccxt.poloniex()
```